# JqGrid 4.4.4 with Toolbar search not shwoing search Operators beside of search textbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Toolbar search in my jQgrid(Version-4.4.4). I have applied `sopt` array to my columns & code snippet is as follows :

```
 colModel: [
        { name: 'IntOrderNo', index: 'IntOrderNo', align: 'center', width: 80, searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]}, search: false },
        { name: 'OrderNo', index: 'OrderNo', searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]} },
        { name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', formatter: 'date', searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"]} },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]} },
        { name: 'Item', index: 'Item', width: 180, sortable: false, searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]} },
        { name: 'Consignee', index: 'Consignee', width: 100, sortable: false, searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]} },
        { name: 'DeliveryDate', index: 'DeliveryDate', formatter: 'date',searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"]} },
        { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 80, align: 'right', searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"]} },
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "bw", "bn", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"]}, search: false },
```

But in my jQgrid below column header, there is no button for selection of  operator like `eq, ne, bw` etc. 
My toolbar search code snippet is as follows and I also attaching snapshot of my grid toolbar search with this post.

```
 }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true,
    beforeSearch: function () {}})
```

[image]

So how I overcome this problem??? Is that I am missing something... or I am doing something wrong???

Answer (score 1):

I think this option was only added in 4.5.* of jqGrid,

i am facing the same issues.